# SQL server job deployment

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssis, sql-clr, deployment

I have a SQL Server job which has got different steps, including running a SSIS package. Currently it is on my PC (my local instance).

I should deploy it to UAT and assume some steps need to be taken to deploy it, in terms of creating login which run it, removing my login from it, etc.

What are the steps involved to deploy it successfully? Please note there is a CLR function call in this job as well; what would you recommend for required security settings around that?

Comment: It's very hard to say really, I would just submit it and rely on server feedback on errors for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

Deploying the stuff you need to move a job is pretty much just like packaging the stuff you need to move application code assuming that you correcly put all the new items and changes in **source control**. This includes your SSIS package, any object creation or alteration scripts such as tables, views, UDFs, stored procs, CLRS (Never ever create database objects using the GUI if you want to deploy later), any scripts to populate tables (such as lookup tables). You may need to number the items in the deplyment folder to ensure they are run in the correct order. Usually I write a deployment document as well because some of what we are deploying will go to differnt servers (Our ssis server is is differnt from our database server).

You can also script out the job, but you will need to review and change the script for the new environment. I often find it just as easy to set up the job on the other server manaully (but I have dba rights to all servers, if you do not, you will probaly need to this).

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing what all the steps of your job do, we cannot provide you a step-by-step instruction to deploy it. You can script out configured SQL Server agent jobs, which may be a starting point.

I would suggest installing another instance on your local machine, unless you happen to have access to a test server. Then take note of everything you do to get your job up and running on that instance. If you can repeat it over and over again, then you have your deployment document completed.